Expo ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync: Show Selected Images in Gallery
I’m building a React Native app with Expo Managed Workflow, and I want to let users pick images from their gallery. With restricted access, users only grant access to the images they select. The thing is, when they go back to pick more images using ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync, I want it to show the ones they’ve already given access to. Anyone know how to make that happen with Expo ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync?
